# Is it possible to activate GTA V on a new PC?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v

I'm buying a new computer in the next days. I need to know if I bought GTA V from Steam or official website now and installed it on this pc, is it possible to install (re-downloading is OK) and activate the game to the new pc when it arrives ?

I'm asking about official ways from official vendors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

When you buy a game on Steam, you can install it on any computer as long as you log to your account. And you'll probably even keep your saves.